# How to make useSelector() work (basic setup)?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am stuck in the most basic of React Redux setups. My useSelector does not return any value at all. Here's the code:
store.js:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'

const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}

const counterReducer = ( state = {initialState}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT': return {counter: state.counter+1}
        case 'DECREMENT': return {counter: state.counter-1}
        default: return state
    }
}

const reduxStore = createStore(counterReducer, {initialState})

export default reduxStore
```

root index.js:

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import reduxStore from './components/store/store'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {/* Redux store provider */}
    <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

App.js:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

function App() {
  const counter = useSelector ((state) => state.counter)

return (<p>Countamount: {counter}<p>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition for your reducer and for your store is incorrect.

Your state looks like this:

```
{
  initialState: { counter: 0 }
}
```

I think you want it to look like this:

```
{ counter: 0 }
```

You need to remove the default value for the state argument in your reducer, and change the call to createStore to just take `initialState` not `{initialState}`. E.g.

```
const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT': return {counter: state.counter+1}
        case 'DECREMENT': return {counter: state.counter-1}
        default: return state
    }
}

const reduxStore = createStore(counterReducer, initialState)
```

Comment: Many thanks! It was, indeed, the accidental deconstruction when declaring the store!

Comment: No problem! I highly suggest using redux-dev-tools to see your redux state and the actions that are being triggered, etc. It would have shown the state above `{initialState: { counter: 0 }}` and that would have helped you to debug the issue.